# Replace mariadb with mysql on Plesk 12.5.30

Tags: mysql, mariadb, plesk

I need to use standard mysql, in plesk it says everywhere that it is mysql but when I login to console it says mariadb.
I understand that it is very similar but this plesk will be hosting staging systems so they must use exactly the technology that the product servers use.

Is it possible to do it somehow using the web interface or do I have to manually install it from console?

Comment: Could you please share which MySQL version you need and which requirements are not satisfied with MariaDB?

Comment: Staging system, so the only requirement is that it is the same as the production system, mysql 5.6.

Comment: Oleg, the function JSON_TABLE isn't supported by MariaDB at least in the version 10.3.25-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it's impossible because `plesk-mysql-server` package has explicit dependency for `mariadb-server`.

Yes, you can solve this with --force, but it means further troubles with plesk updates and upgrades.

If you need DB server for some application you can install it on separate server and register it as remote DB server in `Tool&Settings > Database Servers`.